# Автоотправка текстового поля с задержкой при вводе не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу использовать `oninput` для поля `input`, предназначенного для фильтрации, но мой код почему-то не работает:

```js
$('.filter-form input')
  .attr('oninput', 'setTimeout(function () { this.form.submit(); }, 1000)');
```

Comment: И не будет работать. Зачем функцию вставлять атрибут? Используйте [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). А если не секрет, то как у Вас будет работать фильтрация? Так как при таком подходе данные формы будет отправляться при вводе первого же символа. Будет лучше, если Вы более подробно опишите что есть и что нужно. Также приведите Вашу HTML-разметку.

Answer (score 1):

this внутри setTimeout ссылается на глобальный объект window, а у него нет свойства `form`. Можно сохранить текущую форму вне функции:

```js
$('.filter-form input').attr('oninput', 'var t = this; setTimeout(function () { t.parentNode.submit(); console.log("Отправлено"); }, 1000);');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="filter-form">
  <input>
</form>
```

Но таймаут не стирается после каждого ввода... значит за 1 секунду что успели ввести - то и отправится) Можно перестать извращаться с кодом в одной строке и написать простенькую функцию:

```js
var timeout;
$('.filter-form input').on('input', function(){
  clearTimeout( timeout );
  var t = $(this).closest('form');
  timeout = setTimeout( function(){
    t.submit();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="filter-form">
  <input>
</form>
```

Не будет отправляться до тех пор, пока скорость печати - больше 1-го символа в секунду.